# Clothes revealing skin during movemement

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

[image: issue]

[I'm sorry for the poor quality of the screenshot]

So I was making a female body in blender wearing a skin-tight dress. However, when I tried to change the pose of the character in the Pose Mode, a part of the dress revealed the skin of the base model underneath. What could possibly go wrong?

I'm a beginner in blender and its features. So I'm in need of a little help regarding this issue.

*The clothes are separate from the body but share the same armature.

Comment: clothing is mesh connected to the body sharing the same weight painting? Or separated object somehow connected? Or is it sim? (probably not based on the skirt)

Comment: You'll need to fix it manually. Either by using shape keys or by optimizing your model (by deleting all the hidden geometry i.e. the sking under the clothes) but you'll always end up using shape keys when you want to pose your model since the pose will *always* distort your model in an unwanted way.

Comment: The clothes and the body are separate objects but they share the same armature.

Comment: then it is mqbaka says, you need to move your character in different and most bendy poses to see how your clothing work and repair all the mistakes along the way... this is normal to happen because object don't know that they shouldn't intercept each other, you need to do it manually by fixing weigh paint or in worse case your topology

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: you could also use the Mask modifier in order to mask some parts